# Run Discord bot in a worker service instead of a console app?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net, dsharp+

I want to create a Discord bot and both DSharpPlus and Discord.Net use Console applications in their tutorials.

I would like to know if there are any reasons for this because when thinking about it a worker service application seems to fit better, no? I can setup the bot in the `StartAsync` method and if needed I can dispose all the things in the `StopAsync` method.

So does someone know why console applications are preferred? Perhaps worker services have disadvantages that I am not currently aware of?

Maybe the bot will struggle with the `ExecuteAsync` method?

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think console application was used in examples because Unix systems do not have services like windows does. I guess you can freely develop windows service application and use examples you mentioned.

Please, have a look to: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/07/creating-windows-services-in-net-core-part-3-the-net-core-worker-way/

Comment: My bot runs as a Windows service just fine. The hosting application type is really to the preference of the developer. I actually run my bot through a Windows forms application when I'm troubleshooting and want a UI.

Comment: @IgorGoyda just to make sure we are talking about the same technology. I would like to create a .Net 5 worker service application and use it on my Linux system :)

Comment: Ah, I don't know about Linux, sorry about that ☹

Comment: guys if you want to close this question, why don't you comment at least? Please tell me what's wrong with the question

Comment: @Question3r: The close votes are because it’s an opinion based question that won’t likely lead to a single correct answer. Questions like “why” and “preferred” are usually closed for those reasons.

Comment: @JeremyCaney thanks but I wasn't asking for opinions :) This was a question about technical reasons.

Comment: @Question3r: I understand. The boundaries around opinion-based are a bit fuzzy, and sometimes debatable. Personally, I’d rather more questions about preferences, reasoning, and best practices to be permitted—and especially in cases like this where there are well-established norms. But the community has found they generally yield a lot of answers without a clear solution, which is why you’re getting close votes. Positively, you got a good answer regardless, and even if this question gets closed it won’t get deleted, so others can still learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does someone know why console applications are preferred? Perhaps worker services have disadvantages that I am not currently aware of?

.NET Code declares a cross-platform support that means you can use the same sources for different target platforms. Because of that, .NET have to use kind of "service" idea for long running background things but without a bind to specific platform. On Linux any console application could be a "service" application (have a look: https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-run-a-dotnet-core-console-app-as-a-service-using-systemd-on-linux). On Windows it is a bit different, but still quite simple (have a look: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/07/creating-windows-services-in-net-core-part-3-the-net-core-worker-way/.

> Maybe the bot will struggle with the ExecuteAsync method?

`BackgroundService` class is designed as a base class for any "service", so, I think, there is no better candidate to extend :)

Comment: I was just thinking about this line `await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);`. I'm not sure if the bot "freezes" for 1 second... ?

Comment: @Question3r Whole application won't freeze, just one thread that currently executes this method. I suggest to consider a smaller amount of time, let's say about 100 milliseconds.